# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy_user_agents'

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I tried to use scrapy_user_agents with scrapy-proxy-pool.

I added these lines in my settings.py:

```
    DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_proxy_pool.middlewares.ProxyPoolMiddleware': 610,
    'scrapy_proxy_pool.middlewares.BanDetectionMiddleware': 620,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_user_agents.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 700,
    }
```

when I run my spider, I get this error message:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy_user_agents'

I removed the lines of proxy in the middleware, but I get same issue, same error message.

You will find below the complete log errors:

> 2019-08-13 16:05:28 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.7.3 started (bot: scraping_entreprises)
>   2019-08-13 16:05:28 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.4.1.0, libxml2 2.9.5, cssselect 1.1.0, parsel 1.5.2, w3lib 1.21.0, Twisted 19.7.0, Python 3.7.4 (tags/v3.7.4:e09359112e, Jul
>   8 2019, 20:34:20) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 19.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.1.1c 28 May 2019), cryptography 2.7, Platform Windows-10-10.0.17134-SP0
>   2019-08-13 16:05:28 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'scraping_entreprises', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'scraping_entreprises.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MOD
>   ULES': ['scraping_entreprises.spiders']}
>   2019-08-13 16:05:28 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: 0a7932c1a3ce188f
>   2019-08-13 16:05:28 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
>   ['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
>   'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
>   'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
>   Unhandled error in Deferred:
>   2019-08-13 16:05:29 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "c:\users\nino\pycharmprojects\scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 184, in crawl
>   return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
>   File "c:\users\nino\pycharmprojects\scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 188, in _crawl
>   d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "c:\users\nino\pycharmprojects\scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1613, in unwindGenerator
>   return _cancellableInlineCallbacks(gen)
>   File "c:\users\nino\pycharmprojects\scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1529, in _cancellableInlineCallbacks
>   _inlineCallbacks(None, g, status)--- ---
>   File "c:\users\nino\pycharmprojects\scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
>   result = g.send(result)
>   File "c:\users\nino\pycharmprojects\scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 86, in crawl
>   self.engine = self._create_engine()
>   File "c:\users\nino\pycharmprojects\scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 111, in create_engine
>   return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda : self.stop())
>   File "c:\users\nino\pycharmprojects\scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 69, in init
>   self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)
>   File "c:\users\nino\pycharmprojects\scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader_init.py", line 86, in init
>   self.middleware = DownloaderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler)
>   File "c:\users\nino\pycharmprojects\scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler
>   return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
>   File "c:\users\nino\pycharmprojects\scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 34, in from_settings
>   mwcls = load_object(clspath)
>   File "c:\users\nino\pycharmprojects\scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 46, in load_object
>   mod = import_module(module)
>   File "C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib_init.py", line 127, in import_module
>   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>   File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
>   File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>   File "", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>   File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
>   File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
>   File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>   File "", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>   builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy_user_agents'
>   2019-08-13 16:05:29 [twisted] CRITICAL:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "c:\users\nino\pycharmprojects\scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
>   result = g.send(result)
>   File "c:\users\nino\pycharmprojects\scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 86, in crawl
>   self.engine = self._create_engine()
>   File "c:\users\nino\pycharmprojects\scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 111, in create_engine
>   return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda : self.stop())
>   File "c:\users\nino\pycharmprojects\scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 69, in init
>   self.downloader = downloader_cls(crawler)
>   File "c:\users\nino\pycharmprojects\scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader_init.py", line 86, in init
>   self.middleware = DownloaderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler)
>   File "c:\users\nino\pycharmprojects\scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler
>   return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
>   File "c:\users\nino\pycharmprojects\scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\middleware.py", line 34, in from_settings
>   mwcls = load_object(clspath)
>   File "c:\users\nino\pycharmprojects\scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\misc.py", line 46, in load_object
>   mod = import_module(module)
>   File "C:\Users\Nino\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib_init.py", line 127, in import_module
>   return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>   File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
>   File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>   File "", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>   File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
>   File "", line 1006, in _gcd_import
>   File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
>   File "", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapy_user_agents'

Comment: Do you have `scrapy-user-agents` installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try uninstalling and installing the module again to make sure its installed for your version of python.

> > pip (un)install ModuleName

Comment: Thank you so much. I installed it with Pycharm which said "Sucessfully installed". But when I tried to uninstall with pip, it said "Not installed". So after installation with pip, my script works!! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. But when running `pip list | grep scrapy` the package was there, and uninstalling and installing the model again did not make a difference.

Turns out scrapy was started with the wrong Python. I had to change the shebang in **/home/${USER}/.local/bin/scrapy** from

`#!/usr/bin/python3`

to

`#!/usr/bin/python`

to get rid of the ModuleNotFoundError.